# Problems with robotino_node when using roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, robotino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

When I run roslaunch robotino_node robotino_node.launch, I get the following output which indicates that robotino_node & robotino_odometry_node are missing (when I look in robotino-ros-pkg/robotino_node/bin, there too they are missing):

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 20.0
 * /robotino_camera_node/cameraNumber: 0
 * /robotino_camera_node/hostname: 172.26.1.1
 * /robotino_laserrangefinder_node/hostname: 172.26.1.1
 * /robotino_laserrangefinder_node/laserRangeFinderNumber: 0

 * /robotino_mapping_node/hostname: 172.26.1.1
 * /robotino_node/downsample_kinect: True
 * /robotino_node/hostname: 172.26.1.1
 * /robotino_node/leaf_size_kinect: 0.04
 * /robotino_node/max_angular_vel: 3.0
 * /robotino_node/max_linear_vel: 0.5
 * /robotino_node/min_angular_vel: 0.1
 * /robotino_node/min_linear_vel: 0.05
 * /robotino_odometry_node/hostname: 172.26.1.1
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.9

NODES
  /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    robotino_camera_node (robotino_node/robotino_camera_node)
    robotino_laserrangefinder_node (robotino_node/robotino_laserrangefinder_node)
    robotino_mapping_node (robotino_node/robotino_mapping_node)
    robotino_node (robotino_node/robotino_node)
    robotino_odometry_node (robotino_node/robotino_odometry_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [11321]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 10ff797c-8d13-11e4-8424-001e6537844e
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [11334]
started core service [/rosout]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robotino_node/robotino_node]: can't locate node [robotino_node] in package [robotino_node]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robotino_node/robotino_odometry_node]: can't locate node [robotino_odometry_node] in package [robotino_node]
process[robotino_laserrangefinder_node-4]: started with pid [11351]
process[robotino_camera_node-5]: started with pid [11368]
process[robot_state_publisher-6]: started with pid [11380]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher
[ WARN] [1419607376.930340318]: The 'state_publisher' executable is deprecated. Please use 'robot_state_publisher' instead
[ WARN] [1419607376.934934125]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
rocess[robotino_mapping_node-7]: started with pid [11418]
[ INFO] [1419607378.754853544]: LaserRangeFinder0 disconnected from Robotino.
[ INFO] [1419607379.158983565]: Mapping disconnected from Robotino.
[ INFO] [1419607379.495352459]: Camera0 disconnected from Robotino.
```

Can someone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200083/problems-with-robotino_node-when-using-roslaunch/) by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had checked out robotino-ros-pkg from svn and run 'rosmake robotino'. This is when I got the aforementioned error. But I managed to solve it by excluding all occurrences of KinectROS.cpp which was causing the problems. So now when i run 'rosmake robotino', it generates all executables.

---

Originally posted by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) with karma: 46 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Being able to launch a `.launch` file indicates that your package is most likely correctly referenced by `roslaunch`. So next I suspect the node executable doesn't exist (yet). If the target executable is written in:

- C++: you might have to build. Have you built your package? E.g. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages
- Python: See its mode by e.g. `ls -l %TARGET_NODE_FILE%` and if not set as executable then do `chmod`.

HTH.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam3891](https://answers.ros.org/users/21120/sam3891/) on 2015-01-02**:
I haven't built the package as you have written it, that is because I used "rosmake" and it is supposed to build all the packages isn't it? And in any case, robotino_camera_node, laserrangefinder_node and mapping_node got automatically built so why not robotino_node and odometry_node?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-01-03**:
I suggest you edit your question to add more detail (e.g. all the commands and output of when you build the packages). Otherwise it's hard for us to give help since there's only limited amount of info provided.